# Vuex setting state

Tags: javascript, vue.js, state, vuex

I have a prop that I'm binding to a child component. I'm trying to get rid of this and set the value to a data in a vuex global state.

```
<VideoPip :asset="asset" v-show="pipEnabled === true" />
```

How can I set **this.$store.state.assetVideo;** which is by default an empty object equal to the asset value? Would I do this in a computed property?

Comment: if you are not going to change the value of asset prop in the child component use a computed property or use [mapState](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper)

Comment: asset is an object that changes depending on which video the user has clicked on

Comment: if the change happens in the store mutations doesn't matter

Comment: So I can have a computed property that sets this.$state.store.assetVideo = this.asset?

Comment: Isn't it bad practice to mutate the state directly or something?

Comment: thats what i'm checking for. if the asset prop going to be changed in child component then get rid of the prop and create [Computed Setter](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) in the child component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219151/discussion-between-talal-and-albert-anthony6).

Answer (score 1):

For reading the video state data, you can just use the [`mapState` helper](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper). For example, in your `Video` component

```js
import { mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  name: 'Video',
  computed: mapState(['assetVideo'])
}
```

You can then reference `this.assetVideo` in your component's methods and `assetVideo` in its template. This will be reactive to changes in the store.

---

For setting the value, you should (must) use a mutation. For example

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  strict: true, // always a good idea
  state: {
    assetVideo: {} // personally, I'd default to "null" but that's up to you
  },
  mutations: {
    setVideoAsset: (state, assetVideo) => (state.assetVideo = assetVideo)
  }
}
```

and in your components

```js
methods: {
  selectVideo (video) {
    this.$store.commit('setVideoAsset', video)
  }
}
```

Comment: you beated me to it and basically we had the same idea but i tend to use computed setters

Comment: @Talal I wasn't sure if OP was trying to mutate the value within their `Video` component or elsewhere. I assumed the latter

Comment: OP said that it would be mutated in parent component in chat but the important thing in the question being answered the right way and you nailed it

Answer (score 1):

in your parent component:

```js
// if you dont use namespace
import { mapMutations, mapState } from 'vuex'

export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['assetVideo']),
    asset: {
      get() {
        return this.assetVideo
      },
      set(newValue) {
        this.setAssetVideo(newValue)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapMutations(['setAssetVideo']),
  }
}
```

store

```js
const store = {
  state: {
    assetVideo: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    setAssetVideo(state, payload) {
      state.assetVideo = payload
    }
  }
}
```

in your parent component you can change the state using `this.asset = 'something'` and it will change in store and anywhere else used

and also you can pass it to child components